# ALSA card not outputting any data

Tags: c++, linux, alsa

I'm running the following program from [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735?page=0,1) website:

```
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main() {
  long loops;
  int rc;
  int size;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int val;
  int dir;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
  char *buffer;

  /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                      SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,
                              SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
  val = 44100;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params,
                                  &val, &dir);

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
  frames = 32;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle,
                              params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params,
                                      &frames, &dir);
  size = frames * 4; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
  buffer = (char *) malloc(size);

  /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params,
                                         &val, &dir);
  loops = 5000000 / val;

  while (loops > 0) {
    loops--;
    rc = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
    if (rc == -EPIPE) {
      /* EPIPE means overrun */
      fprintf(stderr, "overrun occurred\n");
      snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
    } else if (rc < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "error from read: %s\n",
              snd_strerror(rc));
    } else if (rc != (int)frames) {
      fprintf(stderr, "short read, read %d frames\n", rc);
    }
    rc = write(1, buffer, size);
    if (rc != size)
      fprintf(stderr,
              "short write: wrote %d bytes\n", rc);
  }

  snd_pcm_drain(handle);
  snd_pcm_close(handle);
  free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

I have tested this program on a few computers and each time the program output some "stuff" to the screen. However when I moved the program to a desktop (which does have a sound card, just no output device plugged into it) it no longer displays anything. I thought it might be the fault of the missing audio output device so I instantiated "snd-aloop" a virtual sound card but when I ran it again specifying that sound card this time there was no output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Outputting some "stuff" to the screen can be done much easier with `printf("stuff\n");`. Why are you concerned that there are no error messages?

Comment: I am also concerned that there are no error messages. I am not sure what to do at this point. Do you think you can help?

Comment: Why do you think that the *lack*  of error messages is a problem?

Comment: Look, I'm really lost, do you think you could just point me in the right direction here? It'd really help...

Comment: When this program runs without errors, it does not display anything. So far, you have not described what the actual problem is.

Comment: This program reads from an audio device and displays it on the screen. When I put this program on a specific machine it does not output anything. This is the problem. It should output a bunch of random characters (which are ascii representation of the audio that is playing). Keep in mind that this program will output a bunch of random characters even when there is no audio playing. That is the problem.

Comment: No, that's not what it does. It reads from its input and writes that data to the sound device.

Comment: Shoot... yes looks like you are correct. I made the incorrect paste originally. I have updated the post with the correct code.

Comment: I'm just trying to get audio from a dummy sound card (snd-dummy). Am I doing something wrong here with my approach?

Comment: The last parameter of `snd_pcm_open()` should be `SND_PCM_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the issue, the dummy sound card is still not outputting anything

Comment: But you'll get an error message if the device is busy.

Comment: There is an error actually after running it a few times. What does that mean? There's got to be something I'm missing here.

Comment: I seriously have no idea why but it has suddenly started working :( I have no idea what I changed. I guess for now this issue can be put to rest